# How to create a FIXED submenu (the dropdown menu should be displayed permanently)

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover, fixed, submenu

I have a menu and a submenu. The submenu is only displayed when hovering over it.
QUESTION 1: I want it to be displayed permanently.
QUESTION 2: I would like it to be displayed horizontally (and not vertically as it is now).
To see what I mean, go to http://appartement-met-zeezicht.be and hover on "English". What is displayed under "English" should be displayed permanently, pereferably in a horizontal (and not vertical) way.
Thanks a lot!!

/*SUBMENU*/

## topmenu ul li ul{ position:absolute;width:150px; z-index:999999;  padding-left:0; margin-left:-10px;  margin-top:24px; display:none;}

## topmenu ul li ul li{ float:none; margin:0; padding:10px 0px; text-align:center; background:#302f2f url(images/pattern.png) repeat;  display:block; border-bottom: 1px solid #333; height:auto;}

## topmenu ul > li ul li:hover{ background:#2bb975 url(images/pattern.png) repeat;}

## topmenu ul li ul li a{ font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; padding:4px;}

## topmenu ul li ul li ul{left: 100%; margin-top:-27px; float:none; margin-left:0px;}

.tinynav, .tinynav1{ display:none;}

Comment: Show some code or what you have done yet? A fiddle maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** it seems that some Javascript is overwriting the CSS, you can try to add this to style.css:

```
#topmenu ul li ul, #topmenu li:hover > ul {
    display: block !important;
}
```

For the second question: in your style.css find the parts below **/*MENU*/** and **/*SUBMENU*/**. *Delete* the next lines below those comments and paste this code instead:

```
/*MENU*/
#menu_wrap{width:100%; float:left; background:#302f2f url(images/menu_wrap.png) repeat;}
.is-sticky{ width:1000px!important;}
#topmenu{text-align:center;}
.menu-header{margin:auto; padding:0; display:block;}
#topmenu ul{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#topmenu ul li{list-style-type:none; display:inline-block; margin-top:0px;padding:25px 15px;}
#topmenu li a{ font-size:18px; color:#fff;}
#topmenu ul > li:hover{  background:url(images/transblack.png) repeat;}
#menu-icon{display:none;}

/*SUBMENU*/
#topmenu ul li ul{ position:absolute;width:auto; z-index:999999;  padding-left:0; margin-left:-10px;  margin-top:24px; display:none;}
#topmenu ul li ul li{ float:left; margin:0; padding:10px 0px; text-align:center; background:#302f2f url(images/pattern.png) repeat;  display:block; border-bottom: 1px solid #333; height:auto;}
#topmenu ul > li ul li:hover{ background:#2bb975 url(images/pattern.png) repeat;}
#topmenu ul li ul li a{ font-size:14px; font-weight:normal; padding:4px;}
#topmenu ul li ul li ul{left: 100%; margin-top:-27px; float:none; margin-left:0px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me so fast! As I am such a PC-dummy, I do not know how to access css of my wordpress site (Theron Lite) in order to remove the "display: none". I only now how to "overrule" things thanks to the "add custom css" plugin. Can you suggest me something to add in this plugin? Or can you show me the way to the css-file of my side? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You have a style,css in your WordPress wp-content/themes/theron-lite folder. Download the file with FTP to your hard drive, open it with a text editor, paste my code into the file, save and upload it with FTP again.

Comment: Waw, fantastic!! Now I finally can access this style.css-document! Dummies as me get smarter thanks to experts like you, thanks a lot!! Adding the codes you suggested did not work, but now I edited my question and added the css code, maybe it's easier to help now?

Comment: Welcome. I corrected now a mistype in my code snippet however there is still some Javascript involved and by hovering **out** the submenu is flickering.

Comment: It works!!!! Don't worry about the flickering, its the imperfections which make life really special :-). I am happy you could help me !

Comment: Now there is only 1 question left over: hog could i put the sub-menu-items next to each other (=horizontally) instead of beneath each other (= vertically). Thanks thanks thanks!

Comment: Yes yes yes, that's exactly what I needed. Fantastic!! Thanks a lot, Johann! I voted you up but that didn't seem to work as I need "15 reputation". You made my day :-)

Comment: Welcome I am glad that I could help :) Thanks for the upvote it worked well and you could also officially "accept" my answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "Hover" this list.
And make this list "display: inline-block;"

Comment: Thanks for helping me so fast! As I am such a PC-dummy, I do not know how to access css of my wordpress site (Theron Lite). I only now how to "overrule" it thanks to the "add custom css" plugin. Can you suggest me something to add in this plugin? Or can you show me the way to the css-file of my side? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You need to make in your side. 
For example, you can show your code in fiddle or codepen and we will change it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this:

```css
ol {
      display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>Spiderman</ol>
  <ol>Wolverine</ol>
  <ol>The Avengers <br>
    <li>Iron Man</li>
    <li>Captain America</li>
    <li>Thor</li>
    <li>Black Widow</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```